# Restricting triggering of GCP Cloud Function to certain IP-range

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, serverless, google-vpc

I use GCP cloud functions to trigger actions based on http-requests from another system. I know the IP-range where the requests come from and I want to restrict triggering the actions only on requests from this IP-range.

How should I go about this? I have tried to add the IP-range as a subnet to my default VPC-network and restrict the cloud function to Allow internal traffic only, but the requests do not come through due to 403 error.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I've never done this, but the docs seem to explicitely mention filtering on incoming IP ranges with the cloud load balancing option: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/networking/network-settings#ingress_settings

Comment: Thank you, I was able to achieve this by using Load Balancing and setting up Cloud Armor for filtering the IP addresses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve this by using Load Balancing-product and setting up Cloud Armor for filtering the IP addresses.